# Sorting saved queries in ADUC console

Tags: active-directory

We have a few dozen saved queries that are often used from the ADUC console. Depending on the order the people add them they can show up in a mismash of orders - it appears that they are sorted by creation date by default and there isn't a ready way to change it.

Are there any tricks I'm missing to get these into an order that I specify, or at least alphabetize them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Built into the ADUC:

You can create multiple folders to help categorize them, such as "User Queries", "Computer Queries", "Used by Helpdesk", etc.

Other than that you are limited to sorting by name or description, so you can alphabetize them based on name.

[image: ADUC queries]

EDIT: It appears that if you create a temp folder and then move the queries in there it will auto-sort alphabetically at that point.  So create your various folders to categorize or just create one called "Temp", move them all in there, and then move them all back under "Saved Queries".

New pic sorted on left (I moved all 3 back into "Saved Queries" by highlighting all 3 and dragging them at the same time):

[image]

Comment: But you can't sort them in the tree in the left pane. You can only sort them in the display pane on the right.

Comment: Ah...I see what you mean (and what he means now by "creation date).  I'll edit my post.

Comment: Nice trick. So when they get out of order, move them to a Temp folder and then move them back. Easy enough.

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping for, thanks. Should have thought of it on my own. :)

Comment: Worth noting when you drag from one folder to another the view customizations, such as added columns like 'modified' or column widths, will all be reset.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth noting, if you use saved query folders in ADUC or an MMC with the ADUC add-in you run the risk of your queries disappearing at random. A fun bug MS has ignored for 20 years.

Because of this I have a messy bundle of queries in the root of saved queries. Or, you could risk using folders and continually save variations of your queries so you can close out without saving and revert if an issue pops-up.

It's super fun to be on your toes all the time, with a keen eye on a folder which magically desinigrate it's contents; and an ultra bonus to have 60 ADUC MMCs on my desktop.

I can arrange them into pretty designs.  I'm sure MS will come through, they just need another 20 years or so to enable  advanced features such as Saving and sorting.